# Browser window flashes white when navigating between pages in Safari on Mac

Tags: safari, navigation

In Safari 5.0.3 on my Snow Leopard Mac, my browser window flashes white when I navigate between pages in my web site. (...but not in Safari in Windows)

One thing that struck me as interesting is that the flash won't happen when leaving my home page: http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/index.html to go to another page, but it will happen when navigating between other pages--a bright flash of white. Any ideas on how to prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: no flashing here... mac os 10.6.6, safari 5.0.3

Comment: @duncmc and @david I don't get a flash when I go from http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/ to http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/about/ or http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/testimonials/ but if I go from those latter two pages, then I get the flash--I'm on the same OS and browser as David and I assume duncmc? Can you guys confirm that there's no flash when navigating from one of those last two pages? Thanks!

Comment: When I navigate between those two page I _do_ get the white flash.

Comment: okay... you're right. there _is_ that white flashing... and the only thing i can think of is the server taking too long to send a response. but in fact i don't know... me sry